# Is there a simple way to sync thunderbird contacts between computers, like firefox sync?

Tags: linux, sync, thunderbird, firefox

I've discovered Firefox Sync a while ago, and it's absolutely awesome. Now of course I'd like most of my software to work this way! So is there a way to get the same behavior with Thunderbird?

Comment: well, actully this is why i like gmail..

Comment: @jokester: gmail is an attractive option, but you have absolutely no control over it. I prefer to keep the option to switch to another provider if I stop liking what google does with my email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options I have used:

- Google Sync which syncs your contacts to Google.
- Contact sync like Addressbooks Synchronizer software which uploads your contacts to a server. (I used an IMAP folder.)

Other options:

- Export contacts and load them into LDAP.
- Use Zindus to sync contacts.  (Same idea as the second option above.)
- Other similar sync options.  Search addons for sync.

EDIT: Contact sync software maintains a copy of your contacts somewhere and synchronizes your contacts to the that copy. The cycle is usually something like:

- Download synchronization copy from server.
- Update local copy with changes.
- Generate new synchronization copy and upload to server.

I am currently using gContactSync to sync my contacts.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you call "Contact Sync"? What is it?

Comment: It synchronizes the contents of your Thunderbird Address Book with an external database in the cloud.  This way if you need remote access to your contacts, you can do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I've decided to try SyncKolab for now (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/sync-kolab/)